# Vagrant metadata.json file not being read

Tags: json, windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to create some `Vagrant` VM's, but whenever I use `vagrant box add`, it says my box doesn't have the `metadata.json` file. This is also sometimes caused when the `metadata.json` file exists but does not have the `provider` line required by `Vagrant.` However, all the boxes I have tried have had this file with the required text, in correct `JSON` format. Usually I have the file say:

```
{
    "provider": "virtualbox"
}
```

I don't believe white space matters, you could probably have hundreds of blank lines & tabs & spaces. The fact that it doesn't throw a different error (usually `Could not resolve host`) means it is finding the VM's.

The funny thing is, my system has the `precise32` sample VM, and `Vagrant` didn't complain when I `vagrant up`ed that. I even copied the `metadata.json` file from there to one of my VM's and tarred it again, but it still didn't work.

I'm not sure if it's related, but when I tried adding the `--provider` flag (as in `vagrant add box /box/path --provider`), it threw the error,

```
c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/comm
and.rb:51:in `parse_options': missing argument: --provider (OptionParser::Missin
gArgument)
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/comma
nds/box/command/add.rb:29:in `execute'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/comma
nds/box/command/root.rb:47:in `execute'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/c
li.rb:38:in `execute'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:478:in `cli'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/bin/vagrant:9
6:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>
'
```

Comment: I am closing this question as Vagrant has been updated since it was asked and there has not been much activity.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, if you are still looking for an answer. Just in case, if some one else is looking for

> metadata.json should be at the root of the structure when you are
>   creating the tar

Try this `tar -czf server-image.box ./*`

---

instead of `tar -czf server-image.box server-image-folder`

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. The `metadata.json` file is at the root, so this could not be the issue. In fact, there is only one level, one folder, so everything is at the "root". I wonder if me being on Windows could be the issue?

Comment: For me this was the exact issue, I was compressing it by selecting the folder with 7zip. The way I have to do it is to go inside the directory, select the files to be added and compress only the files.

Comment: I was using 7zip as well - tarring from inside the vm folder worked like a charm! Thanks!